# Mouse Wheel: How to pass the event to the window beneath

Tags: c++, window, mouseevent, mousewheel, topmost

Our application has a tool window that floats on top of the document windows. It uses the following styles for the tool window:

```
args.style = WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_CAPTION;
args.exstyle = WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
```

The problem is this: I basically want the tool window to ignore mouse wheel events and pass it to whichever window is beneath it. So the user should be able to scroll the document (or another window's content) while the mouse pointer is over the tool window.

Is there a simple way to achieve this, or do I have to implement this the hard way? (Find the window under the mouse that hasn't WS_EX_TOPMOST set, then send it a faked WM_MOUSEWHEEL event.)

This is a C++ project, but I think it's fairly similar in C#.

EDIT: To clarify things, Windows sends WM_MOUSEWHEEL to the window that has the keyboard focus, disregarding the cursor's position. I want to change this and reroute the event to the window under the cursor. I implemented this with the help of WindowFromPoint and PostMessage, which worked well until we introduced tool windows. I basically need a function WindowFromPointButIgnoreTopMostWindows...

Comment: WM_MOUSEWHEEL normally bubbles to the parent when a window doesn't handle it.  That won't typically happen for tool windows since they are owned windows without a parent.  Forward the message explicitly t the owner with SendMessage().

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm going to try this and find the document window by using WindowFromPoint / GetNextWindow.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work, because GetNextWindow always returns a window of the same kind, so if WindowFromPoint returned a top-most window, GetNextWindow only returns the next top-most window, or NULL if there is none. :(

Comment: EnumThreadWindows doesn't work either, because it does not necessarily return them in Z order.